# Помогите разобраться с *.bak файлами в NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Доброе время суток форумчане,

В процессе работы с проектом, в каталогах проекта создаются «*.bak» файлы,

Такой вопрос:

1. Есть ли возможность где-нибудь в NetBeans, указать другой путь, для создания «*.bak» файлов (Запихнуть их куда-нибудь вне проекта, чтоб каталог проекта не замусоривали)? В настройках NetBeans такого не нашел.
2. И вот еще, в https://netbeans.org/projects/www/lists/nbusers/archive/2006-10/message/857 указан путь «*Look in Tools -> Options -> Advanced Options -> IDE Configuration -> System -> System Settings*», но опции « Advanced Options» в окне « Options » я не нашел (версия: NetBeans 8).

Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Konstantin78, у меня при работе с php на седьмой версии ничего такого не было, вы уверены, что это именно netbeans генерирует? Он вроде только nbproject использовал.

Альтернативно могу предложить только забанить *.bak в cvs и спокойно знать, что в репе всегда будет чистая версия.

Comment: Ну если вы 8-мую версию поставите, то можете это увидеть. Например "....php.bak", "....php.bak1", "....php.bak2" и т.д. (без какой-то левой директоррии просто не обойтись). Я бы screenshot предоставил бы, но тут это не предусмотрено